# How to make Observers wait for creation of WebSocket after authentication

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, websocket, rxjs

I'm using RxJs to listen to a stream of data coming off a websocket. In order to use this pubsub socket, I need to first authenticate on another socket which will return the pubsub socket url.

I have this working now with only a single subscriber.  I need to add another, but there are problems with my current approach because both subscribers will trigger the authentication and create a second pubsub socket.

To be clear, there should only be a single authentication socket and a single pubsub socket for the entire application.  But I need the subscribers to "wait" for the authentication to occur before attempting to use the pubsub socket.  Otherwise, the pubsub socket will be undefined (since we only know it's url at runtime).

This is my current attempt:

Websocket.service.ts

```
    private connect(): Observable<IConnectionInfo> {

    if (!this.authObservable) {
      var credentials = {
        "username": "bob",
        "password": "slob"
      }

      this.authObservable = Observable.create((observer) => {
        const socket = new WebSocket(this.authurl);
        socket.onopen = () => {
          console.log("Auth socket opened");
          socket.send(JSON.stringify(credentials));
        }
        socket.onmessage = (event) => {
          var connection_info = <IConnectionInfo>JSON.parse(event.data);
          observer.next(connection_info);
        }

        return () => {
          socket.close(); //invoked on unsubscribe
          console.log("Auth socket closed");
        }
      })
    }
    return this.authObservable;
  }

public open_pubsub(events: string[]): Observable<IPubSubMessage> {

    return this.connect()
      .flatMap((connection_info: IConnectionInfo) => {
        var url = "ws://" + this.hostName + ":" + connection_info.port + "/" + connection_info.ps;

        var subscription = {
          "subscribe": events
        }

        var authenticate_request = {
          "authenticate": connection_info['token']
        }

        if (!this.psObservable) {
          this.psObservable = Observable.create((observer) => {
            const socket = new WebSocket(url);

            socket.onopen = () => {
              console.log("PS socket opened");
              socket.send(JSON.stringify(authenticate_request));
              socket.send(JSON.stringify(subscription));
            }
            socket.onmessage = (event) => {
              var psmsg = <IPubSubMessage>JSON.parse(event.data);
              observer.next(psmsg);
            }

            return () => {
              socket.close(); //invoked on unsubscribe
              console.log("PS socked closed");
            }
          })
        }
        return this.psObservable;
      }
      );
  }
```

And the Observer:

```
getSystemState(): Observable<string> {

    return this._wsService.open_pubsub([MSG_SYSTEM_STATE_CHANGED])
        .map((response: IPubSubMessage): string => {

                console.log(response.payload);
                return "I wish this worked";
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Any help appreciated!

(**EDIT** Based on an answer that appears to have been deleted, but was really quite useful, I modified the code. This fixed part of the problem, but still results in multiple sockets)

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was missing - the magic of the share() operator.

So for both Observables, I do this:

```
this.authObservable = Observable.create((observer) => {
       ...(etc)...
      }).share();
```

And amazingly, only 1 of each socket is created.